# Getting error in nslookup

Tags: linux, networking, cluster, hadoop

I am trying to do `nslookup skhdphost1`  but I am getting below error. When I try to Reverse lookup checking using command `nslookup 172.16.xxx.xx` again getting the same error:

The error message is:

```
[root@skhdphost1 ~]# nslookup 172.16.xxx.xx
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find xxx.xxx.16.172.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

[root@skhdphost1 ~]#
```

My settings are as follow:

Entry in `/etc/hosts` file

```
172.16.xxx.xx   skhdphost1.example.com      skhdphost1
```

Entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network` file

```
NETWORKING=yes
#HOSTNAME=skhdphost1
HOSTNAME=skhdphost1.example.com
PEERDNS=no
GATEWAYDEV=eth5
GATEWAY=172.16.xxx.xxx
```

Entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver      8.8.8.8
nameserver      172.16.xxx.xx
```

Entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
[root@skhdphost1 ~]# vi /etc/nsswitch.conf
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#       nisplus                 Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#       nis                     Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#       dns                     Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#       files                   Use the local files
#       db                      Use the local database (.db) files
#       compat                  Use NIS on compat mode
#       hesiod                  Use Hesiod for user lookups
#       [NOTFOUND=return]       Stop searching if not found so far
#

# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd:     files
shadow:     files
group:      files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files

netgroup:   nisplus

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files nisplus
aliases:    files nisplus
```

I have restarted the network after the above changes but its not working. Can you suggests me the solution for it.

Comment: Check what you have in /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: I have edited the question and provided the detail.

Comment: Do you have DNS record in your name server (nameserver      172.16.xxx.xx)?

Comment: Where I can find that ?

Comment: On the host do you have run DNS server? Check config and find the directory where zone files are stored

Comment: I think I need to set up a DNS zone for my cluster. I have edited the `/etc/hosts` file and provided the detail of all server there. Do I really need to set up DNS zone. Will editing `/etc/hosts` work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24580/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-s-singh).